# Basic auth for images no longer works in WebView on Android 4.4 (kitkat)?

Tags: java, android, webview, webkit, android-4.4-kitkat

In `WebView`, I am displaying a html page that contains images that needs [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). For that I am using [`onReceivedHttpAuthRequest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with [`handler.proceeed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/HttpAuthHandler.html#proceed%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). It is working well on Android 4.3 (and even on Android 2.3.3+).

However, it does not work on Android 4.4 (kitkat), the method `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` is not called. Any hints how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in kitkat: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69189.
So on Android 4.4, I currently have to fetch images in `shouldInterceptRequest`.